# Saving in Magical Record?

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I have written a code to parse some JSON and save data to database via magical record:

```
NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *timesArray = JSON[@"results"];
for (NSDictionary *record in timesArray) {
    Time *newTime = [Time MR_createEntity];
    newTime.distance = record[@"distance"];
    newTime.time = record[@"time"];
    newTime.date = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"date"]];
    newTime.createdAt = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"createdAt"]];
    newTime.updatedAt = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"updatedAt"]];
    [resultsArray addObject:newTime];
}
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:nil];
```

The above code does not save to persistent store. I haven't used Magical Record in a while, and seems saving is different from what it used to be. How do i save my data now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `saveWithBlock`, the code should be

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    Time *newTime = [Time MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
    newTime.distance = ...
    ...
}
```

another way is just replace `saveWithBlock` with `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait`

```
NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *timesArray = JSON[@"results"];
for (NSDictionary *record in timesArray) {
    Time *newTime = [Time MR_createEntity];
    newTime.distance = record[@"distance"];
    newTime.time = record[@"time"];
    newTime.date = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"date"]];
    newTime.createdAt = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"createdAt"]];
    newTime.updatedAt = [[MMXFormatter instance] dateFromString:record[@"updatedAt"]];
    [resultsArray addObject:newTime];
}
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

For More Understanding about CoreData With MegicalRecord I would recommend you to go through this tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/easy-core-data-fetching-with-magical-record--mobile-13680

Comment: Very good tutorial, but honestly the code you provided in answer was much more geared towards what I am looking for. Do you know of any good tutorials that show MR and working on background thread? SO far all that I can find about MR is on main thread

Comment: Official site is a good place to find such tutorials, https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Working-with-Managed-Object-Contexts.md    or     https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md